# android prevent app auto run while usb device plugged in

Tags: android, usb

Follow the tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html I write a app to text. My app will auto run while the `usb device` plugged in. But I don't want it. How can I prevent my app auto run while the `usb device` plugged in?

The following is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class UsbPermissionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "UsbPermissionReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppConstant.USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED,
                        false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "============");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register the receiver in a `activity`

```
registerReceiver(mPermissionReceiver, filter);
```

**But I find this receiver never run!**

Then I try to enumerating devices to connect the USB device:

```
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"), 0);

for (final UsbDevice usbDevice : mUsbManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
    if (usbDevice.getVendorId() == 8263
            && usbDevice.getProductId() == 768) {
        if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
            Log.i("===", "=======================");
            startService(new Intent(AppConstant.SERVICE_ACTION));
        } else {
            Log.i("===", "00000000000000000000000");
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And I `delete` the `manifest config`. So my app can't autorn while `usb device` plugged in. But also have a question: if I don't plug out `usb device` app would not ask for permission again and communicate well, otherwise it will ask for permission again. But I had check the default. I really don't understand, somebody help me.

Comment: in this tutorial you created a brotcastreciever so i gess you have to close the app in android

Comment: I debug my app then find the broadcast receiver cant enter!

Comment: Actually I just using an intent filter to filter the USB device. But I don't want it start my application.